# Within a dataframe, how can we write one row at a time and one column at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm looping through records in a dataframe column and trying to pull geocode data for each. Here's the code that I'm testing.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
for item in df_fin['market_address']:
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(item)
        df_fin.loc['address'] = location.address
        df_fin.loc['latitude'] = location.latitude
        df_fin.loc['longitude'] = location.longitude
        df_fin.loc['raw'] = location.raw
        print(location.raw)
    except:
        df_fin.loc['raw'] = 'no info for: ' + item
        print('no info for: ' + item)
```

I must be missing something simple, but I'm just not seeing what the issue is here.

UPDATE:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
for index, row in df_fin.market_address.iterrows():
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(row)
        row['address'] = location.address
        row['latitude'] = location.latitude
        row['longitude'] = location.longitude
        row['raw'] = location.raw
        print(location.raw)
    except:
        row['raw'] = 'no info for: ' + row
        print('no info for: ' + row)
        
df_fin.tail(10)
```

Comment: You can do this, **but you shouldn't** it is incredibly inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference below code :

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")
for index, row in df_fin.iterrows():
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(item)
        row['address'] = location.address
        row['latitude'] = location.latitude
        row['longitude'] = location.longitude
        row['raw'] = location.raw
        print(location.raw)
    except:
        row['raw'] = 'no info for: ' + item
        print('no info for: ' + item)
```

And if you are more familiar with Pandas, you can use @DYZ's answer.

Comment: Where is the column or field? If I don't specify it, Python doesn't know what to do. If I add it in, like so: for index, row in df_fin.market_address.iterrows():

I get this error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: Could you share your code, more in detail?

Comment: I just added 'UPDATE' based on your suggestion. Thoughts?

Comment: `iterrows` is a function of dataframe. But `df_fin.market_address` is not dataframe. So you can get error.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a function that converts market_address into the address, lat, and long, and `.apply` that function to the DataFrame.

```
def locate(market_address):
    loc = geolocator.geocode(market_address)
    return pd.Series({'address': loc.address if loc else np.nan, 
                      'latitude': loc.latitude if loc else np.nan, 
                      'longitude': loc.longitude if loc else np.nan, 
                      'raw': loc.raw if loc else np.nan})

df_fin.join(df_fin['market_address'].apply(locate))
```

Note that `loc.raw` is a dictionary. When you store a dictionary in a DataFrame, you are looking for trouble in the future.

Comment: Thanks DYZ. When I tried your solution, I got this error message: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'

Comment: I did not handle the case of an incorrect address. (I thought you would do it on your own.) See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for sharing this.